# How to check empty in variable in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, is-empty

I have a variable that can be either empty, number or text.  I like to find only empty one. But the following codes using .length returned null for 0 number, though it returned 1 for "0" string .  .toString.length even didn't work.  Any suggestion?  Thank you!

```
function test() {
  // criteria can be either empty, number or text. How can I check whether the critieria is empty?
  // In the example below, critiera_2.length returned null, not 1.
  criteria_1 = "";
  Logger.log(criteria_1.length);
  criteria_2 = 0;
  Logger.log(criteria_2.length);
  criteria_3 = "0";
  Logger.log(criteria_3.length);
  criteria_4 = "X";
  Logger.log(criteria_4.length);


  criteria_1 = "";
  Logger.log(criteria_1.toString.length);
  criteria_2 = 0;
  Logger.log(criteria_2.toString.length);
  criteria_3 = "0";
  Logger.log(criteria_3.toString.length);
  criteria_4 = "X";
  Logger.log(criteria_4.toString.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
criteria_1 = "";
console.log(criteria_1.toString() == ''); // output: true
```

```js
const test = x => console.log(x.toString()==='');

test("");  // true
test(0);   // false
test("0"); // false
test("X"); // false
```

It's turned out that you don't even need `toString()` it could be just `x===''`

Comment: Thanks a lot! All of yours worked well.  In particular, I liked x===''.

Answer (score 1):

To check for an empty string, a simple approach would be to use === operator

```
if (criteria_1 === "") {
    //...
}
```